# What am I doing wrong with @Valid?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to validate a form with the `@Valid` notation. Basically right now I just want the `author`field not to be null, I'll extend this to everything else if I can get this to work.

Here's my bean :

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "Document")
public class Document implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @NotNull @NotEmpty
    private String author;
    @NotNull
    private String pubDate;
    @NotNull
    private String title;
    @NotNull
    private String editor;

    private String uploadDate;
    private String contentType;
    private long size;
    private Blob content;
    //setters & getters
```

This is the form I am using :

```
<form th:action="@{/upload}" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
        Author: <input name="author" type="text" th:value="${doc.author}" />
    </p>
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('doc.author')}"
        th:errors="${doc.author}">Name error</p>
    <p>
        Publication date: <input name="pubDate" type="text"
            th:value="${doc.pubDate}" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Title: <input name="title" type="text" th:value="${doc.title}" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Editor: <input name="editor" type="text" th:value="${doc.editor}" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Content: <input name="formContent" type="file"
            th:value="${content.formContent}" />
    </p>
    <!--  <p>Content: <input name="contentFromForm" type="file" th:value="${doc.contentFromForm}"/></p>-->
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" /> <input type="reset"
            value="Reset" />
    </p>
</form>
```

And the controller managing the form when it is sent :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/upload")
public String uploadtoDB(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "doc") Document doc,
        @ModelAttribute(value = "content") Content content, Model model, BindingResult bindingResult)
        throws SerialException, SQLException, IOException {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        return "upload";

    doc.setContent(new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(content.getFormContent().getBytes()));
    doc.setContentType(content.getFormContent().getContentType());
    doc.setSize(content.getFormContent().getSize());
    doc.setUploadDate(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(new Date()).toString());

    documentDAO.save(doc);
    return "uploadOk";
}
```

So basically I am using `NotNull`, which should be checked thanks to`@Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "doc") Document doc`. And the error should be displayed with this :

```
        <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('doc.author')}" th:errors="${doc.author}">Name error</p>
```

Cleary I am doing something wrong, because the form is sent without any problem when I leave the author field empty. But what am I doing wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: The `BindingResult` should directly follow the method argument annotated with `@modeAttribute` (as mentioned in the reference guide).`

Comment: Wow, you're my savior, I completly missed this part. I'm gonna take another look at the guide, I must be blind. Thank you so much! Would you mind posting it as an answer ?

Comment: It's nowhere written in the spring [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) though

Comment: The guide are only starters... Guide != [Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args). Which clearly states *To check for such errors add a `BindingResult` argument immediately following the `@ModelAttribute` argument:*